# jest: Testing catch case in utility function that performs a console.error?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

not sure if this possible to test (might have to rethink the function).

I have this utility function:

```
const getProp = (propKey) => {
  const env = getCurrentEnvironment();
  let prop = '';
  try {
      prop = constants.PROPS_TABLE[env][propKey];
  } catch (err) {
      const errorMsg = `Property not found for environment ${env} using key ${propKey}`;
      console.error(errorMsg);
  }
  return prop === undefined ? '' : prop;
};
```

and I have tests for the happy path, but I'd like prove that the error path will call console.error with expected error message.

Is there any way to accomplish this without changing the design of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the fact it is doing a side effect in I/O directly to the console isn't great - but sometimes that's life.

You can:

- Keep a reference to the old `console.error` value - `var error = console.error`
- Set up a spy on `console.error` - `console.error = jest.fn()`
- Assert it is called `expect(console.error.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('`Property not found for environment ....')` with the exact params
- Revert `console.error` to the original value in an `afterEach`

All together it's something like:

```
var error = console.error;

afterEach(() => {
  console.error = error; // revert the spy
});

test('your fn', () => {
  console.error = jest.fn();
  setCurrentEnvironment('test'); // or whatever getCurrentEnvironment accesses
  expect(getProp('non existing')).toBe('');
  expect(console.error.mocks.calls[0][0]).toBe(
    'Property not found for environment test using key non existing'
  );
});
```

Comment: great answer.  just a typo: `console.error.mocks.calls[0][0]` should be `console.error.mock.calls[0][0]`  (I can't suggest an edit without changing at least 6 characters and it's just a 1 character typo)

Comment: well, I'm trying this and getting a TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined .    I'm just going to change my function to throw an exception rather then log to the console.

Comment: I'll give you credit for this since I would think with a bit more work I could get it to work, but not really worth the time.

Comment: @Maniaque that error is from the typo I was referencing.  The approach works, in the test it just needs to be `console.error.mock.calls[0][0]`.

Comment: No, I included the fix you recommended. Still error.

Comment: @Maniaque I'm going to have a hard time debugging your code like this - I believe I answered your original question though. If you're stuck make snippet I can run in my own node and put it on GitHub in a repo or gist and I'll see if I notice anything obvious.